# Is this the correct method for changing dates in Pandas/Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with a "Date Joined" column in the form : "January 5, 2015"
I want to convert to "2015-01-05"

Here is what I have done with pandas :

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    dt_obj = dt.datetime.strptime(data["Date Joined"][i] , "%B %d, %Y")
    result = dt_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    data["Date Joined"][i] = result
```

This works, but I have a feeling this is not really correct and very slow.

Is this the correct method ? Should I proceed differently ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

`data['Date Joined'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date Joined'], format="%B %d, %Y")`

To convert the entire column rather than iterating

e.g.:

```
In [9]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':["January 5, 2015", "January 6, 2015" , "March 5, 2015" ]})
df

Out[9]:
              date
0  January 5, 2015
1  January 6, 2015
2    March 5, 2015

In [10]:
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%B %d, %Y')
df

Out[10]:
              date   datetime
0  January 5, 2015 2015-01-05
1  January 6, 2015 2015-01-06
2    March 5, 2015 2015-03-05

In [11]:    
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date        3 non-null object
datetime    3 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(1)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. That works almost perfectly, in the newly created column I have a time field that does not appear in your example, like this : "2015-01-05 00:00:00"

Comment: Some of your strings may have time values or you're running an older version of pandas that defaults to always showing time even when the time component is `00:00:00`

Comment: OK I'll try to find out, should not be a big deal. Thanks for your answer, I'll note as answered :)

Comment: If you don't want any time components but still want datetime dtype you can do `dt.normalize`: see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html